# How do I guarantee a succesful outcome of the Rannoch: Admiral Koris mission?

Tags: mass-effect-3

I've reached a point near the end where I have a chance to speak with him. What do I need to make sure I do and/or what dialogue choices should I take to ensure that Admiral Koris survives during this mission?

He's apparently trying to hold off a wave of geth. My current dialogue options are "We're coming" or "Hold them off." I'm *assuming* that telling him we're coming to support him is the preferred choice here, but I want to make sure he doesn't die. Which choice leads me to success here?

Comment: I think there is a reputation check at some point, I chose all the paragon dialog options (top right) and managed to convince him to be saved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Say "We're coming", you have to stay with the general. I believe there's a second, later choice where you have to decide to protect him instead of civilians; I think you need to persuade him at some point, so you'll need enough rep; I used the Paragon option which got him to come along.

Always side with staying near, protecting and prioritizing the general and you'll get him out safe, I did in my playthrough.